# How Many $m$ substrings of length $3$ can be chosen from a string of length $n$

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose we have a string of length $n$ like $a_1a_2 \cdots a_n$.

If we want to choose 2 substrings of length 3 then we can do this in 
$2\times (n-5)+ 2\times (n-6) + 2\times (n-7)+ \sum_{i=4}^{n-6} (i-2)+ (n-i-2) $ ways.

The reason is that if the beginning of the first substring be $a_1$ or $a_{n-3}$, then we have $n-3-3+1$ other ways to choose the second substring. If the beginning the first substring be $a_2$ or $a_{n-4}$, then we have $n-3-3+1-1$ other ways to choose the second substring. If the beginning of the first substring be $a_3$ or $a_{n-5}$, then we have $n-3-3+1-2$ other ways to choose the second substring.
If the beginning of the first substring be $a_i$ for $i\geq 4$, then we should count numbers of way which we can choose the second string before and after the first string which would be $i-3+1$ and $n-i-3+1$ respectively.

So by simplification we have $2\times (n-5)+ 2\times (n-6) + 2\times (n-7)+ (n-9)(n-4) $ ways to choose two substrings of length 3 of one string of length $n$.

There are similar questions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113057/how-many-substrings-of-length-m-can-be-formed-from-a-string-of-length-n) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141044/number-of-substrings-of-length-m-in-a-string-of-length-n). But my question is asking for *finding numbers of ways that we can choose **$m$** substrings instead of one substring.*

Edit: We are allowed to choose same strings again. For example, if we have the string $abcabc$ we have two ways to choose $abc$. So the content of the string is not important but the number of ways which we can choose substrings is our goal.

Comment: Are the substrings allowed to overlap?  If the string is "abcabc" are there 1 or 2 ways to pick the pair of length 3 substrings "abc" and "abc" ?

Comment: @kimchilover If the string be abcabc, then we have 2 ways to pick abc.

Comment: Do the substrings have to be contiguous? For example if the string is ABCDEFG, are you allowed to have substring ADG?

Comment: @user326210 No! I shared the links of two similar questions. I think if we were allowed to have ADG, then the answer could be found using permutation.

Comment: Also just to clarify your earlier answer, are substrings allowed to overlap? For example, if the string is ABCDEFG and you want two substrings, can you pick #1 = ABC and #2 = BCD? (It's unclear to me how you get counts like $n-3+1$.)

Comment: @user326210 We are not allowed to have two substrings that overlap each other. If we choose ABC then we can't choose BC for the second string. I think I made a little mistake with my example of 2 substrings of length 3. I have to go now but I will edit and correct it as soon as possible.

Comment: I think I understand then your question is "How many ways are there of finding $k$ nonoverlapping contiguous substrings of length $m$ in a string of length $n$".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The general question is how many ways are there of finding $m$ non-overlapping contiguous substrings of length $k$ in a string of length $n$.
2. For any such arrangement, the $n$ letters will be divided into $m$ substrings of length $k$, plus $n-mk$ remaining letters that weren't included.
3. Hence the problem can be re-described as follows: you have $m$ blocks each representing a substring of length $k$, as well as $n-mk$ blocks each representing an unused letter.  How many different ways can these blocks be arranged in a list?
4. Or, more abstractly: you have $m$ black balls and $n-mk$ white balls. In how many different ways can they be arranged in a list (given that balls of the same color are indistinguishable)?
5. Now we've reduced the problem to a standard combinatorics problem. In general, the number of ways of arranging $a$ black balls and $b$ white balls in a list is ${a+b \choose a} = \frac{(a+b)!}{a! b!}$, because you are essentially taking $a+b$ balls and choosing which $a$ of them will be black.
6. Hence the number of ways of finding $m$ non-overlapping contiguous substrings of length $k$ in a string of length $n$ is:

$${(n-mk) + m \choose m } = \frac{(n-mk + m)!}{m! (n-mk)!}$$

---

Let's look at a specific example. In particular, if we want to find $m=2$ substrings of length $k=3$ in a string of length $n$, there are

$${n - 2(3-1) \choose 2} = {n-4 \choose 2}$$

ways to do it.

- For example, when $n=6$, there is exactly one way [▬ ▬].
- When $n=7$, there are three ways [• ▬ ▬], [▬ • ▬], [▬ ▬ •].
- When $n=8$, there are six ways: [• • ▬ ▬], [• ▬ • ▬], [• ▬ ▬ • ], [▬ • • ▬], [▬ • ▬ •], [ ▬ ▬ • •].
- When $n<6$, there are no ways, etc.

---

And consequently the number of ways of selecting $M$ (nonoverlapping, continguous) substrings of length 3 from a string of length $N$ is:

$${N-2M \choose M} = \frac{(N-M)!}{(N-2M)!\, M!}$$

Answer (score 0):

This can be considered from the standpoint of arranging a mix of 3-length blocks and single items.

Basically we reduce each 3-block to a type-b item, giving $n-2m$ items, and then the arrangement options are  $\dbinom {n-2m}{m}$

[I'm assuming that the substrings cannot overlap in any one choice.]